# Cant get data in model from frontend to backendASP web API Angular

Tags: asp.net, angular, api, model, request

Im trying to Make a login from an angular Frontend to an ASP.net API backend, But when I try to give the data model with the email and password within the request it doesnt reach the backend while the naming is exactly the same.

Here is my Endpoint in ASP:

```
[Route("/[controller]/Login")]
        [HttpPost]

    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginForm loginForm)
```

Here is my class LoginForm in ASP:

```
public class LoginForm
    {
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }

    }
```

Here is my request code in Angular:

```
login(model: LoginForm) {

    console.log(model);

    return this.http.post(this.authUrl + "Login" , model, {}).pipe(
      map((response: any) => {
        const user = response;


        if (user.result.accountID > 0) {
          localStorage.setItem("token", user.token);
          this.decodedToken = this.helper.decodeToken(user.token);
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

Here is my LoginForm Class in Angular:

```
export interface LoginForm {
    Email: string;
    Password: string;
}
```

And here is the console log when I try it out:

```
{Email: 'test', Password: 'test'}
```

And here is the Request Payload from network when i try it out:

```
{Email: "test", Password: "test"}
Email
: 
"test"
Password
: 
"test"
```

It does reach the backend but the model is just not filled in see picture below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how ASP work but i know about Angular.

When you call Backend with Angular, you need to subscribe to the observable for get data.

```
    this.http.get<any>(this.apiURL + "/Login").subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })
```

If you want to handle some error you can do this.

```
this.http.get<any>(this.apiURL + "/Login").subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
    },
    (error) => {
        console.error(error);
        switch(error.status){
            case 404:
                // 404 code
                break;
            case 500:
                // 500 code
                break;
            default : 
                break
        }
    })
```

Comment: Its not that it doesnt reach the backend because it does but the model data is just not filled in, any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: Can you simply display what you get from backend in console ? Or even try with POSTMAN for see what you get ?

Comment: I added a picture to the question with the return model data

Comment: do you have any idea?

Comment: Well like i said , i don't know how ASP work, maybe look about specify format in code ( JSON / XML / HTML format ), but now i can't help you more im sorry.

The only thing that i dont understand is why you have a `user.result.accountID' when you only have email and password in your object

Answer (score 0):

## Make sure you pass header option with 'Content-Type': 'application/json',

### Here is login service for post login form data

```js
        header() {
          return new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          });
        }

        // ----------------------------- LOGIN -----------------------------
        login(model: LoginForm): Observable<any> {
          return this.http.post(this.ApiURL + 'Account/Login', model, { headers: this.header()})
            .pipe(
              map((response: any) => {
                if (response) {
                  this.authService.setUserName(response.userName);
                  this.authService.setAccessToken(response.accessToken);
                  this.authService.setRefreshToken(response.refreshToken);
                  this.authService.setAssignedMenu(response.menuList);
                }
              })
            );
        }
```

### Here is C# Login Method

```
    [Route("Login")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
    {}
```

Comment: i tried this but it still didnt work, i edited the question bevause it does reach the backend but just with no data

Comment: try => **const formdata = JSON.stringify(loginModal);**
and **'Content-Type': 'application/json',** in header